# php code to return in nice html format

Tags: php, html, format

Can someone please help me put this code in nice html format? I spent so much time trying to find an example but I don't even know what to ask in the search box in google... :/

Thanks a million

```
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
if (!$address) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your address.';
if (!$city) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your city.'; 
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.';
if (!$datetime) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter date and time of service.';
```

Comment: Just to clearify, you want to iterate over the `$errors` array and want to place the content in an HTML page, in a nice looking way? If so, do you have an example site on how you want to make it look. So we have an idea.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use `count($errors)`.  You can just leave that empty entirely: `$errors[] = ...`

I guess you want something like this?

```
foreach ($errors as $error) {
   echo '<p class="red">' . $error . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank for the quick reply. It's greatly appreciated. Second, I rather kind of want to format it with tables or divs so that I can include some image on the error return page. Right now, the results come very unpolished... :/ Anyways, is that doable with php process page? Thanks

Comment: Only one complaint: `class="red"` assumes error messages are red. They could be green when the page template is generally red (so to speak).

Comment: @Christian Of course he can use any class or styles that he wants, I was just doing this as a sort of placeholder.  Maybe `class="error"` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @DavorinSavovic you can emit any any html you want through PHP.  This is more a question about HTML I think; it has nothing to do with PHP really.  It also seems like more of a design question than a development one, i.e. not really suited for this website.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(array(
    'name' => 'Please enter your name.',
    'address' => 'Please enter your address.',
    'city' => 'Please enter your city.',
    'email' => 'Please enter your city.',
    'datetime' => 'Please enter date and time of service.',
) as $varName => $errorText){
    if(!$$varName){
        echo "<div class='error error-$varName'>$errorText</div>";
    }
}
```

Want the over-engineered version? There you have it ^

Through CSS, you can specify a custom icon according to error type, for example consider the code below:

```
.error {
    color: red;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}

.error-email {
    padding-left: 24px; // some empty space for background icon
    background: url('images/email-error.png') no-repeat left center;
}
```

In the code above, I'm showing an email icon only for the email error message. This might or might not make sense depending on how you want it to look like. In general, however, I would leave the class names as they are to be flexible, in case in the future I want to do something specific to a particular type of error message.